# Transpose row data to columns by charcter in notepad++

Tags: excel, csv, notepad++, transpose

Is there a way to transpose data in notepad++ by delimiter?

For example, I have many entries of:

```
John Doe
$100
$200
$300
$400
$500
Jane Doe
$1
$2
$3
$4
```

I'm trying to get the output so I can paste to spreadsheet by columns as:

```
John Doe  $100 $200 $300 $400 $500
Jane Doe  $1   $2   $3   $4   $5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far easier to just put your raw data straight into Excel and arrange it there using a formula:

If you put your raw data into column H, starting from H1, then you can put this formula into A1, fill across to F1, then fill down as far as needed:

```
=INDEX($H$1:$H$24,(ROW()-1)*6+COLUMN())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For notepad++ you could use this Regex:

Search: `\v+(?=\h*[$\v])`

Replace by: `\t`

The data will be separated with `tabs` so you should be able to copy-paste it to Excel.

Also, this should work with different number of entries for every name.

You have a demo of the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/gU5w7w/6/)

**NOTE**: I'm assuming that the data for every person starts with `$`